# Getting error while creating classifier for Urbansound8k .tflite model in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, audio, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I have built model [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hissain/urbansound8k-beginners?scriptVersionId=150718773) with urbansound8k dataset. And converted to tflite using following code. Then I was trying to run inference in Android following similar some steps used for [simple audio classification apps](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tflite-audio-classification-basic-android#0):

**Code:**

```
try {
    AudioClassifier classifier = AudioClassifier.createFromFile(this, currentModelFile); //model.tflite
    TensorAudio audioTensor = classifier.createInputTensorAudio();
    record.startRecording();

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            audioTensor.load(record);
            List<Classifications> output = classifier.classify(audioTensor);
            List<Category> filterModelOutput = output.get(0).getCategories();
            for(Category c : filterModelOutput) {
                if (c.getScore() > MINIMUM_DISPLAY_THRESHOLD) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, " label : " + c.getLabel() + " score : " + c.getScore());
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        classifiedResult.setText("Action: " + c.getLabel());
                        classifiedResultScore.setText( "Score: " + c.getScore());
                    });
                }
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this,classficationInterval);
        }
    };

    mHandler.post(run);
    mAudioClassifier = classifier;
    mAudioRecord = record;
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I am getting the following

```
Error getting native address of native library: task_audio_jni
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing AudioClassifier: input tensor 0 is missing TensorMetadata.
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.initJniWithModelFdAndOptions(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.access$000(AudioClassifier.java:74)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier$1.createHandle(AudioClassifier.java:143)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier$1.createHandle(AudioClassifier.java:136)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils$1.createHandle(TaskJniUtils.java:70)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(AudioClassifier.java:134)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.createFromFile(AudioClassifier.java:91)
    at com.samsung.classification.MainActivity.startAudioClassification(MainActivity.java:86)
    at com.samsung.classification.MainActivity.lambda$showActivitySelectionDialogue$0$com-samsung-classification-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:51)
    at com.samsung.classification.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1485)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:376)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1295)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3571)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4751)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
```

How can I resolve this issue?